# 415 Unsupported Media Type angular2

Tags: angular

I was trying out angular2 for JavaScript and I was able to make a `Http.get` request but when I tried to make a `Http.post` request it would return `415 Unsupported Media Type`  error.

The code itself is pretty concise, so I was not sure what could be causing this error. How would I resolve this issue?

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

console.log(headers.get('Content-Type'))            

return this.http.post(this.endpoint_url, data="test.json", headers=headers).subscribe(
    function(response){console.log("Success Response" + response)},
    function(error){console.log("Error happened : " + error)});
```

Comment: 415 will almost definitely be something returned by your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simply trying to post the string `test.json` as body of the request, not the content of `test.json` file.

Also notice that you are using the `=` symbol at the `this.http.post()` arguments. That is assigning the values to the vars and returning them.

In practice your code is the same as:

```
return this.http.post(this.endpoint_url, "test.json", headers).subscribe(...
```

And "test.json" is not a valid JSON string (which seems to be what you want, due to the headers you are setting).

If you want to send `test.json`'s contents, you should first HTTP GET it, an only then send the result as body of the post.

Answer (score 0):

try stringifying your json before entry

```
 this._http.post(this.standardUrl,
            JSON.stringify({
                ClientVersion: '1.0.0.0',
                ClientLanguage: 'en'
            }),  { headers: headers } )
        .subscribe((response: Response) => {
                data = response.json();
            });
```

That will at least provide a json object..